# Iterating and modifying a Pandas Dataframe or groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm new to Pandas and am working with a multi-index data set of the form (made from groupby):

```
Name 
    Year 
        Month 
             Day 
                DataA   DataB   SpeciesName   SpeciesValue
                  A       B         Name1        Value1
                  A       B         Name2        Value2
                  A       B         Name3        Value3
```

For every group (unique Name, Year, Month, Day) only the final two columns have a distinct value the rest of the columns are identical. I want to make each group contain a single row. The row will have the SpeciesName value as the column title and the SpeciesValue value as the entry. For instance, the result of the group above should be:

```
Name 
    Year 
        Month 
             Day 
                DataA     DataB     Name1     Name2     Name3 
                  A         B       Value1    Value2    Value3
```

How would I go about this? Iterate through the dataframe or groupby object and create a new dataframe with the structure I want or is there a better way?

Comment: maybe you can try `df.set_index('SpeciesName').unstack('SpeciesName')`

Comment: Blake, is our row index MultiIndex or your column index?

Comment: @ScottBoston the rows are multiindexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, use `set_index` and `unstack` then `reset_index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Blake']*3,'Year':[2017]*3,
                  'Month':[1]*3,
                  'Day':[15]*3,
                  'DataA':['A']*3,
                  'DataB':['B']*3,
                  'SpeciesName':['Name1','Name2','Name3'],
                  'SpeciesValue':['Value1','Value2','Value3']})

df = df.set_index(['Name','Year','Month','Day'])

df
```

Sample input dataframe:

```
                     DataA DataB SpeciesName SpeciesValue
Name  Year Month Day                                     
Blake 2017 1     15      A     B       Name1       Value1
                 15      A     B       Name2       Value2
                 15      A     B       Name3       Value3
```

Now, let's reshape the dataframe:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['DataA','DataB','SpeciesName'],append=True)['SpeciesValue']\
  .unstack()\
  .reset_index(level=[-1,-2])

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
SpeciesName          DataA DataB   Name1   Name2   Name3
Name  Year Month Day                                    
Blake 2017 1     15      A     B  Value1  Value2  Value3
```

Comment: Thanks, I could needed the data not to be under the SpeciesName like it is in your output. However your answer got me looking at some previously missed Pandas functions that I was able to use. I'll post what I did and you can let me know what you think. Thanks again for your help!